# Conversion error in Visual Studio not showing data types

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015

I'm running into an issue when trying to view a report I set up in visual studio. The report is throwing a conversion error (which I'm familiar with), but it's not showing any information about that conversion error. see screen shot below (I guess I can't embed the image, so please see link). This is running a stored procedure I set up in SSMS, and in that stored procedure everything works just fine. There are three queries and a stupidly simple export with 4 fields. All of the individual queries work just fine.

The conversion error appears to be involving a parameter I set up in the report. This parameter labeled 'performance' is varchar(30) and only interacts with other varchar(30) data types. I literally only compare it to a single field that is of the exact same data type, and do not use the parameter for any other purpose. The reason I say I believe this is the issue is because when previewing the report in visual studio, I can enter a performance name with single quotes around it, and the error doesn't appear (although this isn't helpful because it passes along the single quotes and therefor messes up the match).

I run visual studio and SSMS through a hosted platform, so every angle of this is interacting with a remote server and remote applications. Nothing is stored in house.

Any help here would be much appreciated! I've already discussed this with the company hosting our applications, but without knowing whether or not this issue is server-side or on my end, they're unwilling to assist.

[image]